# (How) can I export a function from a .NET assembly without using C++/CLI?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, c++-cli

I'm working on a C# component which consists of two DLLs:

1. A .DLL written in C++/CLI exporting a symbol; unfortunately, this DLL dynamically links against the CRT and there doesn't seem to be a way around that.
2. A C# assembly.

The C++/CLI DLL gets loaded and then loads the C# assembly (and forwards most calls to it). Is it possibly to simplify this scenario so that I export a symbol from the C# assembly right away?

Comment: The CRT is just another DLL that needs to be copied, don't sweat the small stuff.  Not sure if Gieseke's [DllExport] hack needs the CRT, you'll have to try.

Comment: @HansPassant: The problem is that the application into which the C# component (i.e. the C++/CLI DLL) is loaded may use a different version of the CRT with the same file name. I believe this is at least a problem with Visual Studio 2005 vs. Visual Studio 2005 SP1. So I hoped by just not using the CRT (or linking against it statically) I wouldn't have to bother with the manifest stuff associated with newer VS versions.

Comment: Newer CRT version (VS2010 and later) don´t use a manifest anymore.. they reverted back to dll-hell ;)

Comment: If you can't control the assembly you load then you'll have to make do with what it requires and follow the deployment instructions of the author or vendor.  There's no magic solution for this.

Comment: Which hook do you want to register, and why? Often there are better solutions, such as low level hooks, or global hotkeys.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: I install a `WH_CALLWNDPROC` hook on one of the windows in the .NET process, associating it with the function exported by the .NET assembly. I then send a (custom) window message to the window to trigger that my assembly is loaded into the process. The hook function then uses `ReplyMessage` to yield a handle to a custom message-only window back to the calling process. After this exercise, I can communicate with the .NET process and access the CLR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going for the solution described in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37675/Simple-Method-of-DLL-Export-without-C-CLI

The general approach is to have a dedicated attribute which is used to decorate the functions to be exported. After building the assembly, `ildasm` is used to disassemble it. The resulting IL is patch a little bit so that the previsouly decorated functions are exported, then the IL is assembled into an assembly again.

Answer (score 1):

You can export your functionallity from C# as a [COM server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645738%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) this way it should be pretty easy to call it from C++ as you would do with any other non-C# COM object.

Comment: One thing which complicates things is that the exported function does not get called by me directly. Instead, it's used as a callback pointer with the `SetWindowsHookEx` function, i.e. it's actually Windows which calls my function, not me directly.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe In that case your real problem is that you shouldn't implement that kind of global hook in C#. Either use a low level hook (`KEYBOARD_LL`) or write the code in c. Injecting the CLR into other processes is a really bad idea, doubly so for .net versions before 4.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: I only inject my assembly into processes which already use the CLR.